# msi Installer - Another version of this product is already installed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, guid

How do I change the Product Code for my application within Visual Studio 2010 ?
I've built a new application by reusing an existing workspace by renaming the folders and namespace. Now when I build an msi file file, it asks me to uninstall the existing app on the server (which is a completely separate app) and I'm unable to proceed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start a new project you're supposed to start a new project from scratch otherwise there are things that get left behind. Apart from the ProductCode you may have the same UpgradeCode as the previous product, and it's probably not a good idea to have two separate products installed with the same UpgradeCode.

The easiest way to change the ProductCode in a Visual Studio setup is to go the Properties Window (not Properties) of the project that shows Manufacturer etc, and ProductCode is there too. Just select it and choose "New Code".

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Guid product code in the Visual Studio 2010 using the below tool. And replace the new Guid to the [ProductCode field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367850(v=vs.85).aspx) in your project.

https://weblogs.asp.net/jevgeni/adding-guid-generator-guidgen-to-visual-studio-2010

Comment: Thanks.. Lemme try that fix and rebuild the msi

Comment: That didn't work.. when i generated the msi, the ProductCode entries were removed by the build process and now appear empty